# how do i initialize an array similar to what $.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) will return

Tags: jquery, json

I need to set/initialize an array exactly to what JSON will look like so I can have an array that I can store old and new and compare if `old = new`.

This is what I have:

```
 function refresh()
 {
 var old_json = new Array();
 var old_json["id"] = 0;
 $.getJSON('getMessageDetails.php', function (json) {
    var new_json["id"] = json[0].id
    if (old_json !=  new_json)
    {
        $("#msg_id").html(json[0].id);
        $("#subject").html(json[0].subject); 
        $("#unique_code").html(json[0].unique_code);  
        var old_json = json[0].id;
    }     
}); 
}
```

what I have at the top is not correct.

JSON returns:

```
["id":1,"subject":"freechat"...etc}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var old_json = {};
```

instead of

```
var old_json = new Array();
```

This will initialise the old_json var as an object instead of an array

Comment: ooo yes quite right..forgot sorry..so how can i now do: old_json["id":0]??? so that i can compare json[0].id with old_json["id"]?

Comment: You should be able to compare the old_json object directly to the json[0] object.

Answer (score 0):

javascript array cannot not be associative.

try with "var old_json = new Object();"

you can use a simple variable too "var old_json = 0;"

moreover the assigniation at the end is wrong (var old_json = json[0].id;)

it should be like "old_json = json[0].id;" if you use a simple variable, and "old_json.id = json[0].id;" if old_json is an Object. (suppress the var there, as old_json is already declared)